# kernel base address and ramdisk offset

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm, sony

yesterday I successfully compiled the kernel for the Xperia E4 Dual (E2115).
now I need to pack it with the ramdisk in boot.img using mkbootimg.but the problem is that I don't know the kernel base address and ramdisk offset.
I researched a lot online and found that the base address might be 0x80000000 by checking the first "System RAM" before the kernel code when I do:

```
adb shell 
cat /proc/iomem
```

And also I found a file named "Makefile.boot" in the source which had this:

```
zreladdr-y  := 0x80008000
parhys-y    := 0x80000100
initrd_phys-y   := 0x82600000
```

but when I do:

```
./mkbootimg --base 0x80000000 --kernel zImage --ramdisk_offset 0x02600000 --ramdisk ramdisk.gz -o boot.img
```

and flash it, it won't boot it just stays at the sony logo.

I also tried replacing the zImage with the one i get from extracting boot.sin with flashtool. still the same thing.

so I was wondering if anyone knew the base addr and ramdisk offset or atleast knows how to get those addresses.

EDIT: boot.img link.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-Az_nGTB8cnWGE2U2paal9RX00/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Which exactly kernel and u-boot do you use? Please provide links to corresponding sources (repositories).

Comment: Kernel source:http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/xperia-open-source-archives/open-source-archive-for-24-0-a-5-14-and-24-0-b-5-14/

Comment: ...and U-Boot sources? There were a lot of changes recently to U-Boot, so please provide link to sources.

Comment: I dont know where to find uboot sources. I thought the adresses are suposed to be in the header but i dont know how to read it.sorry for noob

Comment: Do you have at least original `boot.img` (image which contain `zImage` and `ramdisk`)? If so -- it's possible to read those addresses from its header. Let me know if you are able to extract that file (it's usually flashed to `boot` partition). I can help you from there. Also, tell me you managed to get to U-Boot shell (via serial console probably).

Comment: i searched the web far and wide and only two tools can unpack the boot.img. a perl script from DoomLoRD and sonys flashtool. flashtool has an option to dump header so i will upload it to google drive and post a link

Comment: It's quite easy to extract and interpret `boot.img` header, really. Take a look at [`struct image_header`](http://git.denx.de/?p=u-boot.git;a=blob;f=include/image.h;h=1e686b76d3eb0090b502253687b1d445e1f80970;hb=HEAD#l305) in U-Boot sources. One can easily write some C app that uses that struct and extracts all fields appropriately. So if you actually have `boot.img`, you can share it with us, we can look for addresses in its header.

Comment: @SamProtsenko edited the post with a link to bootimg

Comment: None of those files is `boot.img`, seems like those are just ELF files (you can check it using `file` tool actually). So I don't think you can extract any useful data from those files. You need actual `boot.img` file in , which usually can be obtained from `boot` partition. Without original `boot.img`, we can't move any further, as we don't know addresses which must be provided to `mkbootimg` when creating custom `boot.img`.

Comment: Thats because its sonys format. The one in the folder from_phone is from the boot partition of my phone. Pulled using dd.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Sony `boot.img` format. Do you think it has load address in it? And have you tried to extract those addresses?

Comment: Just quick look got me these links, may be helpful: [\[1\]](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=2qo6AwAAQBAJ&pg=PA313&lpg=PA313&dq=boot+image+sony+format&source=bl&ots=0lBTRic4fQ&sig=wD995EX0U5EWJ7G13BdBI2VFEfM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiAnZKG6KjSAhXMBSwKHT1TDGwQ6AEILzAD#v=onepage&q=boot%20image%20sony%20format&f=false), [\[2\]](https://forum.xda-developers.com/crossdevice-dev/sony/tool-unpack-format-sony-kernel-image-t3530077), [\[3\]](https://github.com/Tasssadar/libbootimg/pull/2). Also I tried to use `binwalk` tool, which shows me that your firmware image contains ELF and some compressed data

Comment: @SamProtsenko thank you for your help.i followed the link you gave  and found a tool that got me the information i needed.

Comment: Would be nice if you share that information (which tool you used, and which useful info you obtained) with us. So that if someone runs into the same issue, can use your results.